# Alternative to using strncpy() as 'safe' version of strcpy()

Tags: c, strings

I am thinking of using this as part of a header file to give me a useful string-manipulation tool. Elements is size of dest to prevent overflow:

```
int copystring(char *dest,char *source,int elements)
{
    int run,omitted=0;
    for(run=0;run<elements-1;run++)//last reserved for'\0'
    {
       dest[run]=source [run];
       if (dest[run]=='\0')
       { 
           break;
           //doesn't increment, so a below will be '\0'
       }
    }
    //now see if characters missed out, starting from first non-copied character 
    char a=source[run];
    while (a!='\0')
    {
       run++;//move on to next char in source
       omitted++;// missed out one more char
       a=source[run];
    }
    dest[elements-1]='\0';//could add an if condition if omitted is 0 
    return omitted;///tells parent function how many letters weren't copied
}
```

It may be worth my while adding a macro defining maximum amount of omitted chars to check for, and if exceeded to return -1.

Advantages: terminates in null charcter like strcpy while avoiding overflow like strncpy; returns the amount of characters, if any, that were omitted, so saves writing bit of code for handling this if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few comments.

1. The standard type for specifying something like the maximum length of a string is `size_t`. You should probably use that instead of `int`.
2. traversing the remainder of the string on the off chance that somebody *might* want to know how much was skipped seems like poor design. Unless you know you're going to use that (frequently), I'd advise against it. If somebody wants that information, `strlen(s) - size` is pretty trivial to type, so it's not like you're saving them something terribly arduous.
3. I think most people accustomed to C would probably use pointer notation throughout.

   ```
   char *copystring(char *restrict dest, char const *restrict source, size_t elements) {
       char *d;
       for (d = dest; d + 1 < dest + elements; d++, source++)
           *d = *source;
       *d = '\0';
       return d;
   }
   ```
4. This returns a pointer to the end of the new string, which frequently *is* quite useful. For example, if you're building up a string with data filled in at appropriate points, it's often useful to limit the size of each field you insert to a specific maximum, then get a pointer to where you're going to add the next item (though, in fairness, something like `snprintf` is often more convenient still).

Comment: hmmm, lots to think about. I was considering two versions, one with just 1 and 0 returns to let me know if all data has been used,-for instance to inform on program output- as well as this, but never thought about returning a pointer for the end, so that's something to consider.

Comment: 1) This sample code has 2 compiler errors.  suggest review. 2) Would prefer code that gracefully handles the corner case `copystring(dest, source, 0)` rather than going UB.

Comment: @chux: I've fixed the typos. Not sure there was any UB before, but I've modified the code to at least make it clear that the source and destination should be distinct.

Comment: After switching from `signed` to `unsigned` for the buffer size, if `elements == 0`, the code has an integer overflow problem.

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't look like a string copy function as the loop does not break when the _null character_ of `source` is encountered.